# How can I hover on an element and change the style of far ancestor?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
    <div> 
        <nav>
           <ul>
               <li>
                 <a class="link" href="/">Link</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the background colour of the div with the class header-wrapper when hovering on the link.
Can I do this with just css or scss?

```
a.link:hover {
.header-wrapper {
    background: red;
   }
}
```

And several more variations of this, parent selector in scss.

Comment: nope, this is like parent-inception.- their question is "How do I select the <li> element that is a direct parent of the anchor element?" Also this question was asked 9 years ago - I'd prefer a cleaner solution - not using js if possible

Comment: @Jessica: Perhaps that question should be revised to change "parent" to "ancestor" in general since most developers do incorrectly refer to distant ancestors as parents... in any case, it doesn't matter whether the element you want is a parent or a distant ancestor, there is no clean CSS solution for it.

Comment: Even so, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector#answer-1014958) was updated this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no way to select the parent with only `css`,`scss` though they work for [Selector-4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo).
Now you have to use `javascript` or `jQuery` for your purpose because `select-4` doesn't support for all browsers yet.
Fortunately you could use  selector `:has()` in the `jQuery`.

```
    $(".header-wrapper:has(a:hover)").addClass("hoverlink");
```

[Here is an example](https://jsfiddle.net/u7q8cp0n/13/)